# PHP Error this site requires JavaScript enabled

Tags: javascript, php, android, mysql

When I am trying to write some data from my Android app to the MySQL database on free hosting, it gives me this error:

> This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in
>   your browser or use a browser with Javascript support

The free hosting is infinityfree.net, so is this the limitation in the free hosting or is there any way to enable it on the website? I tried another free hosting website 000webhost and it worked very well so the code is well, but I didn't use 000webhost because it uses PHP 5.2 and I need 5.3+.

Comment: Not all mobile browsers support JavaScript. Please try again on a computer

Comment: Wow, I am also facing with same problem.. did you find any answer.

Answer (score 1):

Based on their support forums, this is a common error when their site detects that you're trying to run bots from their service. They don't allow this, and so it probably has nothing to do with your code.

Comment: You are right because it worked well in other sites, Do you know any good free hosting for php 5.3+ that didn't block this service

Comment: I'm sorry, but I really don't have many recommendations for free hosting. Furthermore, automated scripts such as bots are often abusive on servers, and most hosting companies would disallow them. Sorry that I couldn't help more!